# Any Nginx configuration suggestions for a site with a lot of traffic

Tags: nginx

The server with Nginx installed gets about 50 connections per seconds. Sometimes, it spikes to 150 connections per seconds. It has 7GB RAM memory.

This is first time using Nginx and not sure if the default configuration is suitable for this type of server. Any suggestion how Nginx should be configure for a server with a lot of connections and big RAM.

This is EC2 Large instance:

> Large Instance 7.5 GB of memory, 4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores
>   with 2 EC2 Compute Units each), 850 GB of local instance storage,
>   64-bit platform

Comment: Honestly if you want a site with dynamic content (php/rails/etc) to perform well with 50 conc visitors do not host it on EC2.The per dollar computing power EC2 offers is abysmal. For the price of the high CPU instance you can skip the virtualization layer altogether and get a dedicated box. If you must host a site on cloud services why use amazon that uses 10yr old hardware which garners about 40x less performance than competitors for at least 4x the cost? I just don't get why people host always-on sites here except for perhaps leveraging their other services that cannot be replicated

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like it might handle the load.

What you really need to do when you're looking at something like this is to setup the server, then [benchmark](http://www.xenoclast.org/doc/benchmark/HTTP-benchmarking-HOWTO/) it. If it handles the load, great! If not, repeatedly tune until it does or your gains are so small that you need another plan.

Here's a good write-up of somebody pulling [12,000 requests per second](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2010/09/12000-requests-per-second-with-nginx-php-and-memcached/). The same guy has an ["Optimizing Nginx for High Traffic Loads"](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/04/optimizing-nginx-for-high-traffic-loads/) article.